# Model moved from original position in object mode

Tags: objects, object-mode, origin

My model appears in the viewport as it should in edit mode:
[image]

But down here in object mode:
[image]

And when I try to move it, the origin moves instead and this happens:
[image]

So it appears that something at the origin is moving and taking the model with it rather than the model itself. But this isn't the case in edit mode and I'm not sure why. Thanks!

Comment: Probably due to the cloth sim, try setting the animation timeline frame to 1 or hide your modifiers

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I accidentally pressed play with the cloth mod on @NascentSpace